# Create Unit Tests command not found in the context menu?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

I'm using VS 2017 enterprise edition.

I have a solution with an Asp.Net core (on full .Net framework) project. I created a test project using template "Unit Test Project (.Net Framework)" and added the reference to my Asp.Net project.

However, there is no "Create Unit Tests command" in the context menu when I right click the public method? The page I referred is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/create-unit-tests-menu

Comment: did you update to 15.2?

Comment: Yes. It should be the newest version.